# Display custom field without plugin in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

See I have a problem / I now want to display a custom field in a place where this field has several options that I tick if I see it in the product tab. If I do not show, do not display the following codes. Thank you.

1. The code below shows the field:

   ```
   $badges = get_field('badges_product'); 
   if( $badges && in_array('licensed', $badges) ): 
       ?>
       <p>Test</p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
2. But despite this code does not display:

   ```
   get_field('badges_product');
   ```
3. If I put this code instead of the code above:

   ```
   global $product;
   $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'badges_product', true );
   echo ''. sprintf( __( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ).'';
   ```

Now I'm going to put the third code in place of the second code, but I can not do anyone can help me out? Thanks

Comment: Your question is totally unclear and not understandable… could you please reword it. If you are using Advanced custom fields plugin, you should mention that in your question.